# How to change all view text size in android

Tags: android

I want to add an item on menu to adjust the application font size. and if font size be changed by user with this feature all the font sizes of texts in views of application be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to adjust the font size of my application but here i am keeping it stable at scale 1 which you can change accordingly.

```
    public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
}
```

Just change the configuration.fontScale to any value you like and call it in onCreate. Hope this helps.

Comment: ` @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out);
        adjustFontScale(new Configuration());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}` i use this but dont work

Comment: after setting the content.   adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());

Comment: i change to this @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.fade_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());} but dont work yet

Comment: currently the configuration is equal to 1 change it to 1.2 or 1.3 and try then